# How to replace "#N/A" with 0 in mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to replace **"#N/A" values with 0** in all attributes of xml.

Input xml:

```
<DTOSteps>
    <DTOStep Order="1" Name="Rated Premium" Operation="=" Factor="#N/A" Value="#N/A">
        <DTOSteps>
            <DTOStep Order="1" Name="Property Damage" Operation="=" Factor="#N/A" Value="#N/A">
                <DTOSteps>
                    <DTOStep Order="1" Name="AOI" Operation="=" Factor="#N/A" Value="#N/A"/>
                    <DTOStep Order="2" Name="Base" Operation="-" Factor="#N/A" Value="#N/A"/>
                    <DTOStep Order="3" Name="Deductible" Operation="-" Factor="#N/A" Value="#N/A"/>
                </DTOSteps>
            </DTOStep>
            <DTOStep Order="2" Name="Business Income And Extra Expense" Operation="+" Factor="#N/A" Value="#N/A">
                <DTOSteps>
                    <DTOStep Order="4" Name="AOI" Operation="=" Factor="#N/A" Value="#N/A"/>
                    <DTOStep Order="5" Name="Base" Operation="-" Factor="#N/A" Value="#N/A"/>
                    <DTOStep Order="6" Name="Deductible" Operation="-" Factor="#N/A" Value="#N/A"/>
                </DTOSteps>
            </DTOStep>
        </DTOSteps>
    </DTOStep>
    <DTOStep Order="2" Name="Term Factor" Operation="X" Factor="#N/A" Value="#N/A"/>
</DTOSteps>
```

Expected output: https://github.com/Manikandan99/Map_request/blob/main/Response_dwl.xml

Any ideas please on how to replace in dataweave 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the script given below.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
var updateAttribute = (element) ->
  element mapObject (value, key) -> {
    (key) @(
        (
          if (key.@?)
            (key.@ mapObject ((attr_value, attr_key) -> { 
                    (attr_key): if (attr_value == "#N/A") "0" else attr_value
                }))
          else {}
        )
    ) :
    if (value is Object)
      updateAttribute(value)
    else value
  }
---
updateAttribute(payload)
```

Comment: Good Job Sudhish.....